# Why does my Python code add additional characters when writing and reading a file

Tags: python-2.7

I am just learning how to code in Python and have not been able to find a solution or answer as to why when I attempt to read a file that has just been written to it bears additional characters.

***Code***

```
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, source, copy = argv

print "We'll be opening, reading, writing to and closing a file"
opensource = open(source)
readsource = opensource.read()
print readsource
print "Great. We opened and read file"

opencopy = open(copy, 'w+') #we want to write and read file
opencopy.write(readsource) #copy the contents of the source file
opencopy.read()


opensource.close()
opencopy.close()
```

***Output***

[image]

***Contents***

```
test    °D                                                                                                               Îƒ ø U     ø U     ` 6    ` 6     0M     Ð
```

I am running version 2.7 of Python on Windows 7 Professional 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a Windows issue with reading a file opened with "w+" directly after a write.
Start with adding two print statements like this:

```
opencopy.write(readsource) #copy the contents of the source file
print opencopy.tell()
opencopy.read()
print opencopy.tell()
```

And run this on a file with only as contents the words 'test' + CR + LF, you get as output:

```
We'll be opening, reading, writing to and closing a file
test

Great. We opened and read file
6
4098
```

(If you do the same under Linux, the read does not work beyond the end of the file (and you get two times the value 6 from opencopy.tell().)

What you probably want to do is:

```
print opencopy.tell()
opencopy.seek(0)
print opencopy.tell()
opencopy.read()
print opencopy.tell()
```

You then get 6 and 6 as output from tell(). Now this results in reading the word 'test', that
you just wrote.

If you do not want to read what you just wrote, put `opencopy.flush()` between the read and the write statement:

```
opencopy.write(readsource) #copy the contents of the source file
print opencopy.tell()
opencopy.flush()
opencopy.read()
print opencopy.tell()
```